# Database connection failed.Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.9' (13)

Tags: mysql, database, centos, connection

I have my php application coding in 192.168.0.8 but the database is in 192.168.1.9. When i tried to connect in CentOS server its throws error as Database connection failed.Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.9' (13). but when i tried connect the same DB from my localhost then its working. Can someone help and save my day. I also tried editing etc/my.conf file but nothing worked.

Comment: First try to verify network connectivity  (ping) then verify the port is open.

Comment: network connectivity is working. How do i check the port. Its seems the port is open. Because from my local xampp the DB is connecting.

Answer (score 1):

I found issue. It is because httpd_can_network_connect was disabled by default. Now i have set to enabled using setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1 and its working now. Thanks for you interest.